# Oracle SQL- procedure- insert into foreign table from own table not updating the table

Tags: oracle, schema, procedure

Problem- cannot insert data from own schema's table to foreign schema's table.
Details- I am trying to insert the latest data from my own schema table to a foreign schema table. I have all the rights on the foreign schema table. The table structures are exactly the same. The foreign table already has some data but I need to load incremental data with a check on duplicity based on a field called `SURVEY_ID`. There is no error message.
The statement 'NOT IN (SELECT SURVEY_ID FROM FORG.PROD_CL)' is somehow hampering the insert process. If I remove this 'NOT IN' clause and rather mention specific SURVEY_IDs, the data load takes place.

Here is the code-

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FORG.PROD_CL
SELECT 
RESPONSE_ID,
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(COMPLETION_DATE)) AS COMPLETION_DATE,
TO_TIMESTAMP(COMPLETION_DATE||TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(COMPLETION_TIME,11,32))) AS COMPLETION_TIME,
Q101,
Q101_LONG,
Q191,
SURVEY_ID,
REP_NAME,
ATOMIC_TS
FROM OWN1.IPROD_CL
WHERE OWN1.IPROD_CL.SURVEY_ID NOT IN (SELECT SURVEY_ID FROM FORG.PROD_CL)
ORDER BY SURVEY_ID;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is your question? And you should use NLS-parameters for your cast of dates/timestamps.

Comment: As an aside, your `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(COMPLETION_DATE))` and `TO_TIMESTAMP(..)` calls without format masks look wrong. Don't ever rely on NLS_DATE/TIMESTAMP_FORMAT parameters, as these can very easily differ, and you have a bug-in-waiting. If you are simply wanting to remove the time portion, use `trunc(your_date)` (and you can pass in an optional format mask to decide the level it gets truncated to, the default is day).

Comment: @ThomasStrub is there a "not" missing in your comment?

Comment: Thank you both. My additional information is- the statement 'NOT IN (SELECT SURVEY_ID FROM FORG.PROD_CL)' is somehow hampering the insert process. If I remove this 'NOT IN' clause and rather mention   specific SURVEY_IDs, the data load takes place. 
My question is- in what conditions this NOT IN  does not work, specially when selecting data from one schema's table and inserting in another schema's table.